# Send command and exit using python pty pseudo terminal process

Tags: python, shell, eof, pty

Using python pty module, i want to send some commands to the terminal emulator, using a function as stdin (as pty module wants), and then force quitting. I thought about something like

```
import pty
cmnds = ['exit\n', 'ls -al\n']
# Command to send. I try exiting as last command, but it doesn't works.

def r(fd):
    if cmnds:
        cmnds.pop()
        # It seems is not executing sent commands ('ls -al\n')
    else:
        # Can i quit here? Can i return EOF?
        pass

pty.spawn('/bin/sh', r)
```

Thank you

Comment: You might want to investigate pexpect, which is designed for this sort of thing: http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: I just tried and couldn't make it work but from the docs I get the function is for interacting with the output not to receive the list of arguments

Comment: So there is no way to send strings as stdin?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `pty` module does not allow you to communicate with the terminal emulator Python is running in. Instead, it allows Python to pretend to *be* a terminal emulator.

Looking at the source-code of `pty.spawn()`, it looks like it is designed to let a spawned process take over Python's stdin and stdout while it runs, which is not what you want.

If you just want to spawn a shell, send commands to it, and read the output, you probably want Python's `subprocess` module (in particular, if there's just one command you want to run, the `subprocess.Popen` class' `.communicate()` method will be helpful).

If you really, really need the sub-process to be running in a pty instead of a pipe, you can use `os.openpty()` to allocate a master and a slave file descriptor. Use the slave file descriptor as the subprocess' stdin and stdout, then write your commands to the master file descriptor and read the responses back from it.

Comment: Could you add a piece of code when using os.openpty()?