# Issuing commands to psuedo shells (pty)

Tags: python, shell, pty

I've tried to use the subprocess, popen, os.spawn to get a process running, but it seems as though a pseudo terminal is needed.

```
import pty

(master, slave) = pty.openpty()

os.write(master, "ls -l")
```

Should send "ls -l" to the slave tty... I tried to read the response os.read(master, 1024), but nothing was available.

EDIT:

Also tried to create pty's, then open the call in a subprocess -- still didn't work.

```
import pty
import subprocess

(master, slave) = os.openpty()
p = subprocess.Popen("ls", close_fds=True, shell=slave, stdin=slave, stdout=slave)
```

Similar:

[Send command and exit using python pty pseudo terminal process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710829/send-command-and-exit-using-python-pty-pseudo-terminal-process)

[How do *nix pseudo-terminals work ? What's the master/slave channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel)

Comment: You don't need a pty to run `ls`. A pipe will work with that just fine. What did you try there?

Comment: I am using `ls` to test the functionality.

Comment: In your edit, you are mixing pty and pipe. Don't do that. Use one or the other.

Comment: How would I get the output of `ls` in a `pty` then?

Comment: I suggest using forkpty and os.read() from the returned file descriptor. Here's an example [proctools.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/process/pycopia/proctools.py#512).

Answer (score 2):

Use `pty.spawn` instead of `os.spawn`. Here's a function that runs a command in a separate pty and returns its output as a string:

```
import os
import pty

def inpty(argv):
  output = []
  def reader(fd):
    c = os.read(fd, 1024)
    while c:
      output.append(c)
      c = os.read(fd, 1024)

  pty.spawn(argv, master_read=reader)
  return ''.join(output)

print "Command output: " + inpty(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: In Python 3, replace the return with: `return b''.join(output).decode('utf-8')`