# Executing sudo using pty.spawn()

Tags: python, linux, sudo, tty

I am attempting to execute `sudo -S id` within a `TTY` shell using `pty.spawn()` in `python 2.7`.

```
import os
import pty
command = 'id'

scmd ="sudo -S %s"%(command)

def reader(fd):
  return os.read(fd, 50)

def writer(fd):
    yield 'password'
    yield ''

pty.spawn(scmd, reader, writer)
```

when I execute the above code the python interpreter outputs the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

My code is based on this answer:
[Issuing commands to psuedo shells (pty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442360/issuing-commands-to-psuedo-shells-pty/21444480#21444480)

Even when the password is correct I receive the above error, how do I fix this code so that it executes `sudo` and prints the output of the `id` command to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need to provide the command as an array, and using a generator writer does not seem to work, and you need a newline in the password, so try:

```
def writer(fd):
    return 'password\n'

os.close(0)
pty.spawn(scmd.split(' '), reader, writer)
```

Using `os.close(0)` stops the program from putting stdin into raw mode.

Comment: Receiving this error: Password for <user> to change to user=(root) Password incorrect. Sorry, try Again

Comment: I cannot help with that. Note that sudo is asking for your password, not root's password.